# MPAndroidChart, how to center XLabels above grid-lines?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a simple linechart with [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart):

```
chart.setDrawYValues(false);
chart.setDescription("");
chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(true);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

XLabels xl = holder.chart.getXLabels();
xl.setCenterXLabelText(true);
xl.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);

YLabels yl = holder.chart.getYLabels();
yl.setLabelCount(5);

// set data
chart.setData((LineData) mChartData);

chart.setDrawYValues(true);
chart.setValueTextSize(20f);

// zooming on both axis
chart.setPinchZoom(true);
chart.animateX(1000);
```

But I have a visualization problem. Labels on the X axis aren't under the relative grid line, but between the two lines (on Y axis I don't have this problem). Is there a way to put Y labels exactly under the relative grid line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling this:

```
XLabels xl = chart.getXLabels();
xl.setCenterXLabelText(true);
```

will cause the labels to be drawn **between the lines**. If you call `setCenterXLabelText(false);` the labels should be exactly **above** the individual grid-lines.

Also check the example project `LineChart`. There the labels are exactly above the lines.

**Update**

There is no `getXLabels` method in version 3.1.0. Use this:

```
chart.xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
```

Comment: Is this solution this relevant? There is no `getXLabels` method in version 3.1.0